# Equivariant (co)homology of the rotation action of the circle on the plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

What is the equivariant (co)homology of the rotation action of $S^1=SO(2)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Could you edit in what you have tried?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Well, the Borel construction should be a $\mathbb{R}^2$-bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^2$ which is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Then this question looks silly.

Comment: First, I think you mean $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$. 
Second, I don't think thequestion is silly, I think anyone learning equivariant cohomology tries something like this as their first example.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes I meant $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb R^2$ is equivariantly contractible, so it has the same cohomology as $H^*_{SO(2)}(pt) = H^*(CP^\infty)$.

Comment: Good point, thank you.

Comment: I think one just needs contractibility, not equivariant contractibility.  For, if $E$ is any contractible space on which $SO(2)$ acts, then $E\times ESO(2)$ is a contractible space on which $SO(2)$ acts freely, so the quotient $E_{SO(2)}$ is homotopy equivalent to  $BSO(2)$.